# Set dbpath in MongoDB homebrew installed (Mac OS)

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

Hello I installed Mongodb via Homebrew. 
On Mac OS Yosemite.
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8

What I want to achieve is to not have to every time put the **--dbpath /path...** everytime but just **mongod**

Now I have to write:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb/
```

It works fine.

My problem is that when I try to begin mongod with:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

It does nothing. Is that normal?

My config file is:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Is there a way to create a config file that mongo reads automatically so I can run **mongod** without extra parameters?

Or a way to set the dbpath to /usr/local/var/mongodb by default?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I also installed MongoDB using Homebrew and simply added the following to my `.bash_profile`.

```
# MongoDB Aliases
alias mongod="mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork"
```

So every time I run `mongod` in the terminal, it reads from the configuration file and forks the process.

Comment: nice, but can you explain what the fork option is doing here? Just curious.

Comment: When using --fork like you did, I get this error `BadValue: --fork has to be used with --logpath or --syslog`...maybe different mongodb version.

Comment: The `--fork` flag causes the `mongod` process to run in the background. You don't need to include it if you want to run `mongod` in the foreground, but indeed it requires a `--logpath` option to ensure that it can log somewhere. Check your mongo.conf file to ensure that the `logpath` option is included.

Answer (score 0):

mongod --directoryperdb --dbpath /usr/local/folderName/mongodb/3.4.10/data/db --logpath /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.4.10/log/mongo.log --logappend --rest